# Ansible - Centos machine, ansible_lsb is empty

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Running ansible 2.4.2.0,

on a remote Centos machine, ansible_lsb is empty

when running 
**ansible -m setup hostname**
I get

```
...
"ansible_lsb": {},
"ansible_lvm": {
...
```

clones of the same machine show a full map, "major_release" is what I really need.

other attributes are fine, such as:

```
"ansible_distribution": "CentOS",
"ansible_distribution_file_parsed": true,
"ansible_distribution_file_path": "/etc/redhat-release",
"ansible_distribution_file_variety": "RedHat",
"ansible_distribution_major_version": "7",
"ansible_distribution_release": "Core",
"ansible_distribution_version": "7.5.1804",
```

What can I do to populate ansible_lsb ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to install the `redhat-lsb-core` package on the remote machine.

```
yum -y install redhat-lsb-core
```

Comment: Cheers. Not sure why this isn't installed. Anyway, I wonder if there's any reason why we shouldn't just use "ansible_distribution_major_version"